itinerary creator interface into Divi website
how to implement an itinerary creator interface e.g. the travefy API into a divi wordpress website ? , are there API's out there that would allow an itinerary creator interface that uses the drag and drop feature to be implemented in a divi wordpress website, if so which ones ? or is it easier to use some form of divi extension if so which one ?  Detourons itinerary creator interface is a good example of what i am looking for. Detouron interface
I tried using the travefy API but apparently you can use their itinerary automation api with divi

You need to create customs module for this because Divi theme does not has module for this.
